Two-level system and a classical oscillator - energy
I have solved two related problems and have some questions about the results.

Forced classical oscillator with the following equation:

$$\ddot{x}+\omega_{0}^{2}x=\varepsilon e^{-\gamma t}\sin\omega t,\qquad x\left(0\right)=0,\qquad\dot{x}\left(0\right)=0.$$

Quantum two-state system, derived from harmonic oscillator 0 and 1 states with the same force acting as a perturbation:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{C}_{1}\\
\dot{C}_{2}
\end{array}\right]=-ie^{-\gamma t}\sin\omega t\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \Omega e^{-i\omega_{0}t}\\
\Omega e^{i\omega_{0}t} & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
C_{1}\\
C_{2}
\end{array}\right],$$
$$\Psi = C_1 \psi_0 + C_2 \psi_1,\qquad C_1(0)=1,\qquad C_2(0)=0,$$
$$\hbar \omega_0 = E_1-E_0,\qquad \Omega=\frac{m\varepsilon}{\hbar}\left\langle \psi_{0}\right|x\left|\psi_{1}\right\rangle = \sqrt {\frac{m\varepsilon^{2}}{2\hbar\omega_{0}}}. $$
The exact solutions are long, so instead I'll show approximate results for the quantity I was interested in.
The total energy transferred to the system from time $t=0$ to time $t\to +\infty$ under the condition $|\omega-\omega_0| \ll \omega_0$ and $\gamma \ll \omega_0$.
$$E_{cl}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}+\frac{m \omega_0^2 x^2}{2} \right) = \frac{m\varepsilon^{2}}{8\left[\left(\omega-\omega_{0}\right)^{2}+\gamma^{2}\right]}$$
$$E_{q} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \hbar \omega_0 \left|C_2 \right|^2=\frac{\Omega^{2}\hbar\omega_{0}}{4\left[\left(\omega-\omega_{0}\right)^{2}+\gamma^{2}\right]}= \frac{m\varepsilon^{2}}{8\left[\left(\omega-\omega_{0}\right)^{2}+\gamma^{2}\right]}$$
In other words, I obtained exactly the same result, under the assumptions stated above.
What I wanted to ask, does this make sense physically? I know that two level system is kind of the quantum version of a simple oscillator, or we could even say that I was solving the actual quantum harmonic oscillator, but only restricted myself to two levels because of the resonance condition. Still, it was surprising to me that I obtained the exact same formula.
I'm also going to compare the exact solutions, but the quantum case is very hard to solve exactly.
Edit: I did some numerical calculations. For the quantum two-level system the $E(\omega)$ dependence looks very similar to the classical oscillator, but not the same.
"Resonant" means the approximation $|\omega-\omega_0|\ll\omega_0$ in both cases. The time step seems large, but I used an implicit 4th order scheme, so it's pretty accurate. Just to clarify, I used numerical integration for the two-level system, both exact and approximate. For classical system I used the actual exact solution.


Could you clarify your quantum problem? Did you considered a quantum harmonic oscillator with periodic perturbation? What do you mean when you say "same force as perturbation? Why to consider just first two states?

I meant the same force as in the classical case (or rather, its corresponding potential energy). I considered the two level system, but I used harmonic oscillator basis for the matrix element $\Omega$ computation. @Ruffolo In any case, the quantum problem is fully stated in the post, there's no missing information as far as I can see.

I see, thank you for clarification. I was just struggling to figure out the potential, since you considered a damped force. It is very similar to the Rabi problem, but there the oscillator is damped, not the force. I never heard about an exact solution of this problem, from what source are you basing this on?

@Ruffolo, there's an exact solution not just of Rabi problem, but of a more general case. However, it involves special functions and is very complicated. As for this case, I don't have a source, I did my own calculations to figure out the exact solution. Well, it's still approximate, but more complicated that what I've shown here. It presents C2 in terms of Bessel functions of a complex order.

@Ruffolo, I added a picture in case you'd be interested

Looking for your question again, it came to me that what you have in quantum version is initially a coherent state (the ground state). These states are known to be semiclassical, so it's not a surprise that it "responds classically" to an external force. I would say that the average position and average momentum of $\psi_0$ behaves exactly like an classical harmonic oscillator. In averages, both problems are the same one.

I already started to answer in comments, but I'll add some details here, about my reasoning. First, I think we should have some clarification about this problem using two tools: the Heisenberg picture and the Ehrenfest theorem. We could check, for example, in this nice Roger V. answer, that for a narrow wave packet, or an harmonic potential, we would have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle=\frac{\langle p\rangle}{m},
\frac{d}{dt}\langle p\rangle=-\frac{dV(\langle x\rangle)}{dx}
$$
To include the effect of the external force, we should take into account the potential $V_{int}(x) = \epsilon x e^{-\omega t}\sin(\omega t)$. In general, we would include $\langle - \frac{d}{dx}V_{int}(x)\rangle$, but it will result in  $ \epsilon  e^{-\gamma t}\sin(\omega t)$ so
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \langle x\rangle +\omega_0^2\langle x\rangle = \epsilon e^{-\gamma t}\sin (\omega t).
$$
For the state $\psi_0$, $\langle x\rangle = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \langle x\rangle = 0$, so we have the same problem as your classical case, but for the variable $\langle x\rangle$.
Now, solved this problem, we can calculate the mean energy. We have the quantum Hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal H = \frac{1}{2m}p^2 + \frac 12 m\omega_0^2 x^2 + V_{int}(x)
$$
So $E_{q} = \langle \mathcal H\rangle$. The unperturbed part is easy, since it is quadratic. For the interaction part, the quantity will match the classical case if we can guarantee that $\langle V_{int}(x)\rangle = V_{int}(\langle x\rangle)$. But this potential is linear in $x$, so the condition is always fulfilled. The conclusion is that the mean energy should match the classical case.

That's pretty cool, thanks. I didn't remember this special fact about harmonic potential. So I guess I'll add some nonlinear terms and see how that goes.

Now my theory is that if I consider more energy levels in the current problem, I'll get a better agreement with the classical result. That's also something I want to check.

The conditions for the Ehrenfest theorem to hold are match for all states of the oscillator. What could change is the initial conditions, which means that the corresponding classical theory would be different.
